# How to repeat copy paste in VIM?

Tags: vim

I am editing some json files which I would like to replace the same field in multiple places. I am using VIM, I am not sure what is a quick and easy way. For example:

```
data1:
    field1:
        {Some data}
    field2:
        {Some data}
data2:
    field1:
        {Some data}
    field2:
        {Some data}
data3:
    field1:
        {Some data}
    field2:
        {Some data}
data3:
    field1:
        {Some data}
    field2:
        {Some data}
```

And I would like to replace `field1: {some data}` with something else by pasting in all the entries. How can I do that? Some kind of paste and repeat would be nice. Please note `some data` could be another multi lines chunk with indentation rather than just a single line of data.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use global substitution `:%s/field1: {some data}/something else` should work.

Or actually, since `field1:` and `{Some data}` are not on the same line, something like `:%s/field:\n\s\+{Some data}/something else` (the `\n` matches a line break, and the `\s\+` one or  more whitespace characters).

For more info, do `:help :s` in vim.

Comment: I dont think `:s` is quite suitable. Some data could be another nested dictionary with lots of fields. and indentation. I think `:s` is more suitable if what to be replaced is small. preferably single line.

Answer (score 0):

With `:help :global` and `:help :normal`, assuming what you want to "paste over" is the last yanked thing:

```
:g/field1/normal V/field2/-^M"0]p
```

with `^M` obtained with `<C-v><CR>`.

Breaking it up:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line matching `<pattern>`.
- `field1` is your `<pattern>`, matching every line containing `field1`. I will leave it up to you to figure out the correct pattern for your actual use case.
- `normal ...` executes the following normal mode macro from the command line.
- `V/field2/-^M` enters visual-line mode and extends it to the line above the next `field2`. Again, use whatever pattern works for you.
- `"0]p` puts the text from register `0` over the visual selection, respecting the indentation of the first line of the selection.